# How to pass data to java script file in BB10 cascades.?

Tags: javascript, c++, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to show line,bar and candle charts in BB10 cascades.
I have all 3 java script files, but I need to pass data to those script file through c++ code.
How can I do that in BB10 cascades.?

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .cpp file in **main**

```
qml->setContextProperty("app", this);
```

then somewhere else in cpp

```
QString ApplicationUI::myFunction() {
    return "my data";
}
```

and you call it from QML like this (put this in onCreationCompleted):

```
var data = app.myFunction();
```

Make sure that function is Q_INVOKABLE in .hpp file!

A little documentation on this: [C++ and QML integration](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/)

Comment: But is it really QML or pure Javascript file?

Comment: Well you use javascript to call c++ methods in QML file. So, it is a javascript call in QML. I don't really know you meant